# (Three.js /Three.js Editor) How to make a realistic car turning effect?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a little project in Three.js.  It's a car, that you can drive. So far, I've gotten it to go forwards, backwards, (With the Arrow Keys), and have it's front wheels turn either left, or right, based off of what key you press (Also With the Arrow Keys, either Left or Right Arrow Keys), which was a problem I was previously having.  Now, however, I've ran into another issue: how can I make the entire car turn, realistically? If I just make it rotate the car, it rotates around the center, which doesn't look really realistic. How can I make it look like how a car actually turns, in Three.js? Is this possible? If so, how can I do this? Id prefer to try to do it with just Three.JS, if possible.

Also, just some more information:
The script is attached to the mesh called *chassis*, which is just a stretched out and slightly-flattened cube. When the chassis moves, the wheels update to move with it. I need to rotate the chassis.

If anyone needs any more information, please, let me know!
And please, if anyone has any ideas, or can help, please, do!

Thanks!

Example / Current Project attached below, along with the formatted script, I'll label **currscript.js**.

[The project](https://repl.it/@SpencerLeagra/Threejs-Car#currscript.js)

Comment: I unforutnately do not have à code example but you might want to look at the ackerman steering method :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry

Comment: I don't think I entirely understand, but just to make sure it's clear, I've already got the wheels themselves to turn, I'm trying to figure out how to make the entire car to turn when you press the left or right arrow keys, in a realistic way.

Comment: which is what Ackermann allows to do the principle is to make your car rotate around a point, the more the car brakes, the smaller the diameter of this circle is and the sharper the turn :
https://doc.babylonjs.com/snippets/car_driven

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't know how to use Babylon.js within the Three.js editor, how could I do this? Is there a way to do this with Pure Three.js?

Comment: There has to be but unfortunately i am unable to provide such code since I don't know enough about this specific topic, I'm really hoping for someone else to answer this question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yeah, I don't know either.